# Show image in Tkinter for python 3.2

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter

How to display an image in Python 3.2 using Tkinter? The PIL doesn't work so something that doesn't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Tkinter `PhotoImage` class to create an image object, then assign this object to the `image` attribute of a `Label` widget.

For more information see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: Can you please show me an example? I just need a window with a basic image in it and a label. The image is in the same directory and is named image.gif . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\pictures\pic1.gif")
label = Label(image=photo)
label.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

## try this (for python 3)

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage




photo = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/pile.gif")
lb=tkinter.Label(root,image = photo)
lb.grid(row=4, column=1)
```